# Problemas com utf8_decode no retorno de array

Tags: php, ajax, utf8-decode

Estou com um problema que me deixou bastante confuso. Tenho uma página no php que faz cadastro de Ministérios. Nela envio os dados via ajax para para outra página php fazer a inserção, e a inserção ocorre sempre de maneira normal. Seguem os códigos:

Ajax que envia os dados

```
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "ajax/insertMinisterio.php",
    data: {
      name: name,
      alternativename: alternativename,
      description: description
    },
    success: function (result){
      var returnjson = JSON.parse(result);
      var type = returnjson['type'];
      var msg = returnjson['message'];

      alert(msg);
      //reloadMinisteriosTable();
    } // Fim success
  }) // Fim ajax

});
```

Página que recebe os dados do ajax

```
<?php   
    include '../../class/autoload.php';

    $database = new Database();
    $ministerio = new Ministerio();

    $name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
    $alternativename = utf8_decode($_POST['alternativename']);
    $description = utf8_decode($_POST['description']);


    $ministerio->setNome($name);
    $ministerio->setNomeAlternativo($alternativename);
    $ministerio->setDescricao($description);
    $ministerio->setStatus(1);

    try{        
        $database->database_connect();

        $query = "INSERT INTO pibjm_ministerio (nome, nome_alternativo, descricao, status) VALUES ('{$ministerio->getNome()}', '{$ministerio->getNomeAlternativo()}', '{$ministerio->getDescricao()}', {$ministerio->getStatus()})";

        $result = mysqli_query($database->database_connect(), $query);

        if($result){
            $finalresult = array("query"=>$query, "type"=>"success", "message"=>"Ministério cadastrado com sucesso!");
        } else {
            $finalresult = array("query"=>$query, "type"=>"error", "message"=>"Não foi possível cadastrar o ministério! Tente novamente!");
        }

        echo json_encode($finalresult);
    }
    finally{
        $database->database_close_connection();
    }

?>
```

O grande problema estou tendo no uso do **utf8_decode**. Quando eu o uso em qualquer uma das variáveis, ele até faz a inserção normal no banco de dados, mas sempre retorna no ajax com o **result vazio**. E eu preciso do utf8_decode porque ele deixa a acentuação certa. Se eu usar htmlentities, utf8_encode, ou qualquer outra função do php nas variáveis, tudo também funciona, porém no retorno do ajax **voltam os dados que eu desejo**, só que no cadastro no banco a acentuação fica errada. Testei diversas soluções e não consigo resultado. Qual o problema que o utf8_decode pode estar dando ali no php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função json_encode só aceita valores em utf8, se tiver um único caracter em outra codificação ela irá retornar null.

Aplique utf8_encode em todos os elementos do array, antes de passa-lo ao json_encode.

Comment: hum beleza Jader, depois vou testar aqui e já te falo

Comment: Ao analisar melhor seu relato, percebi que na verdade você esta tendo problemas para recuperar os dados do bd e provavelmente esta tentando obtê-los por ajax/json, então editei a resposta.

Comment: Então Jader, resolveu meu problema, porém não apliquei utf8_encode em todos os elementos do array, passei apenas na query e resolveu!